# Wrong index sent to my file event handler?

Tags: angular

i am working in an app for handling text and files and i noticed something strange.
since i use a dropzone component to reuse across multiple endpoints, i noticed that when i try to upload a file, the index in the ng for returns the first index with a image type for all the image index

```html
<div formArrayName="content">
        <div *ngFor="let subContent of chapterContent.controls; let indexed = index" [formGroupName]="indexed">
            <mat-form-field style="width: 100%;" *ngIf="subContent.get('type').value == 'text'" >
                <mat-label>
                    Introduce el contenido aquí
                </mat-label>
                <textarea matInput formControlName="content" cdkTextareaAutosize #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize" cdkAutosizeMinRows="5" cdkAutosizeMaxRows="20"></textarea>
                <mat-error>¡No dejes el campo vacío!</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <div *ngIf="subContent.get('type').value == 'image'">
                <file-dropper (file)="pushFile($event, indexed)" ></file-dropper>
            </div>
            <button mat-raised-button color="warn" type="button" (click)="removeContent(indexed)">
                Eliminar
            </button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>
                    Selecciona un tipo de contenido
                </mat-label>
                <mat-select (selectionChange)="updateSelector($event)">
                    <mat-option value="text" selected>
                        Texto
                    </mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="image">
                        Imagen
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
            <button type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="addContent()">
                Añadir Contenido
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```js
async pushFile( file : File, indexed : number){
    console.log(indexed);
    console.log(file);
  }
```

if i run this code and read the console logs for two images dropzones it will return something like

> file.png

> 0

> file2.png

> 0

Comment: it really didn't help that much, i've read that part yet it doesn't clarify it

Comment: oh, alright! then i'll check the correct sintax

Comment: i don't get it, i checked giving it as the input, but when i emit it it turn from the index that it should be back to be the first one